# Inconsistent undefined behavior

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

For a class, I wanted to demonstrate undefined behavior with `goto` to the students. I came up with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        goto x;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                x: printf("%d\n", i);

        return 0;
}
```

I would expect the compiler (`gcc` version 4.9.2) to warn me about the access to `i` being undefined behavior, but there is no warning, not even with:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 test.c
```

When running the program, `i` is apparently initialized to zero. To understand what is happening, I extended the code with a second variable `j`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    goto x;

    for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < 10; i++)
            x: printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the compiler warns me that I am accessing `j` without it being initialized. I understand that, but why is `i` not uninitialized as well?

Comment: That's kind of the thing with undefined behavior, it's *undefined* and really anything can happen. :) However, this is more about the compiler than about the behavior being defined or not when running.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, but why does the compiler recognize UB for `j`, but not for `i`? They are declared and accessed in the exact same way.

Comment: Interesingly, I get a warning for the `i` in both the programs when using `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3`, but not when using `-O0` or not using `-Ox`.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized, but the compiler doesn't know it at compile time.  This case is very simple, but in general, the problem is what's known as undecidable (like the halting problem).  The compiler cannot, in general, determine if there is a dynamic path to a use of `i` that does not pass through an assignment to `i`.  If it could, then it could solve the halting problem, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy: Me too. That is strange. That is not supposed to happen, right?

Comment: Lest we confuse writing code that *performs* undefined behavior vs. tasking a compiler with *catching us doing it*. And just for kicks, reverse the usage of `i` and `j` in your `printf` argument list, leaving them as-is in your loop decl list.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I agree with you, but why does it know for `j` when it is declared and accessed in the exact same way as `i`?

Comment: @Andreas Unterweger Because there's only one assignment to `j`, and that assignment is unreachable (the initialization of both `i` and `j` is dead code).  In the case of `i`, even if the initialization is ignored, there still remains an assignment (the increment, `i++`).

Comment: The clang compiler gives a clue. The warning is that `i` is uninitialized in `i < 10`. So if you change, `i < 10` to `i < 10 && j < 10`, then I expect you'll get the warning for `j`.

Comment: If you use `for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < 10; i++, j++)` instead (ie. also increase `j`) it also is not found by the compiler. This does *NOT* tell you whether it *is* UB or not -- the compiler does at it's best.

Comment: @TomKarzes,user3386109: That seems logical, thank you.

Comment: On [https://gcc.godbolt.org/](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) you can explore different compilers and look at the generated assembly code. You will also see that your code won't compile on some compilers, others produce warnings.

Comment: The behaviour of your code and compiler is **consistently** undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined behavior is a run-time phenomenon. Therefore it is quite rare that the compiler will be able to detect it for you. Most cases of undefined behavior are invoked when doing things beyond the scope of the compiler.

To make things even more complicated, the compiler might optimize the code. Suppose it decided to put `i` in a CPU register but `j` on the stack or vice versa. And then suppose that during debug build, it sets all stack contents to zero.

If you need to reliably detect undefined behavior, you need a static analysis tool which does checks beyond what is done by a compiler.

Comment: I think that the first sentence is misleading, considering OP is specifically asking about behaviour during translation phase.

Comment: This is it. Declaring the variables explicitly as `register int` makes the warnings appear for both.

Comment: @user694733 UB is about execution. The compiler just can only try to find out what's going to be executed and hint at you that something is possibly UB when executed.

Comment: @larkey UB covers both, translation and execution, as described 3.4.3 of N1570. My point was that UB isn't *only* a run-time phenomenon, as witnessed by OP.

Comment: @user694733 It is only UB to _use_ the value of an uninitialized automatic variable. The use occurs in run-time. It is perfectly fine to have a program with uninitialized variables that aren't used. The compiler is not required to warn you about that. Suppose I have code like `for(int i = 0, x; i<sizeof(x); i++)`, that would be perfectly safe and well-defined, even though `x` is never initialized.

Comment: @Lundin That is different case, because value of `x` isn't read. In OP's situation `i` *is* used without being initalized. In that case compiler is allowed to behave irrationally, even when the actual use would happen at run-time.

Comment: @user694733 Ah, okay I understand what you mean. Yes, in general, UB can also be during translation time. Although this UB has *at least* to be in a documented manner.

Answer (score 2):

> Now the compiler warns me that I am accessing j without it being
>   initialized. I understand that, but why is i not uninitialized as
>   well?

Thats the point with undefined behavior, it sometimes does work, or not, or partially, or print garbage. The problem is that you can't know what exactly your compiler is doing under the hood to make this, and its not the compiler's fault for producing inconsistent results, since, as you admit yourself, the behavior is undefined.

At that point the only thing thats guaranteed is that nothing is guaranteed as to how this will play out. Different compilers may even give different results, or different optimization levels may.

A compiler is also not required to check for this, and its not required to handle this, so consequently compilers don't. You can't use a compiler to check for undefined behavior reliably, anyways. Thats what unit tests and lots of test cases or statistical analysis is for.

Answer (score 2):

Using "goto" to skip a variable initialization would, per the C Standard, allow a compiler to do anything it wants even on platforms where it would normally yield an Indeterminate Value which may not behave consistently but wouldn't have any other side-effects.  The behavior of gcc in this case doesn't seem to have devolved as much as its behavior in case of e.g. integer overflow, but its optimizations may be somewhat interesting though benign.  Given:

```
int test(int x)
{
  int y;
  if (x) goto SKIP;
  y=x+1;
  SKIP:
  return y*2;
}

int test2(unsigned short y)
{
  int q=0;int i;
  for (i=0; i<=y; i++)
    q+=test(i);
  return q;
}
```

The compiler will observe that in all defined cases, test will return 2, and can thus eliminate the loop by generating code for test2 equivalent to:

```
int test2(unsigned short y)
{
  return (int)y << 1;
}
```

Such an example, however, may give the impression that compilers treat UB in a benign fashion.  Unfortunately, in the case of gcc, that is no longer true in general.  It used to be that on machines without hardware traps, compilers would treat uses of Indeterminate Value as simply yielding arbitrary values that may or may not behave in any consistent fashion, but without any other side-effects.  I'm not sure of any cases where using `goto` to skip variable initialization would *yet* cause side-effects other than having a meaningless value in the variable, but that doesn't mean the authors of gcc won't decide to exploit that freedom in future.

Comment: I do not understand what this has to do with my initial question (about the specific code that I posted). This seems to be a completely different case of UB.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger: Sorry--I thought your point of confusion was with the concept of "undefined behavior", since if you understood that you wouldn't find anything "surprising" about gcc's treatment thereof; if you want a good example and understand anything of machine code, the godbolt.org site is nice because you can see very quickly how slight changes in code affect the output.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger: Quick experimentation doesn't reveal anything alarming about gcc's "goto" optimizations, but does show some ways in which it's clever.  I'll update the code above to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is much clearer to me now.